# Insert formula that contains dynamic cell reference using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to be able to pass a dynamic cell reference into a formula in a cell and need to use VBA to do it.

i = 2
If I need to reference B2 I'd do the following:
formula = "= "B" & i" 
But that doesn't work.

How do I do this? 
Thanks.

Edit:

```
Sheets(v).Range("K" & 2).Formula = "=networkdays(b" & i & ", today())"
```

That's my code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to quote "B":

```
.Formula = "=B" & i
```

---

There are other ways, such as:

```
.Formula = "=" & Cells(i, "B").Address(False, False)
```

---

The OP changed the question:

```
.formula = "=networkdays(b" & I & ",today())"
```

Comment: That's not working. I need it to do this .formula = "=networkdays(b & I, today())

Comment: You changed the question.. I've added to my answer.

Comment: I use your exact formula and get error: "expected: end of statement

Comment: It works for me. Add the code you are using to the bottom of your original question. You are placing a reference to a cell (Range) before the dot of `.Formula` aren't you?

Comment: The code you've added to your question also works for me, providing **v** is an existing worksheet-name or index.